# Exact relation between kernel and invertibility of a differential operator

Tags: partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, inverse

Let's assume we have a differential operator $D$ and a differential equation
\begin{equation}
Df=j
\end{equation}
What is the connection between invertibility, the kernel of the operator and the initial conditions we have to provide.

Example: Let's look at the general Maxwell equation
\begin{equation}
\square A^{\mu}-\partial^{\mu}\left(\partial_{\nu} A^{\nu}\right)= j^{\mu}
\end{equation}
Fourier transformation yields
\begin{equation}
\left(-k^{2} \eta^{\mu \nu}+k^{\mu} k^{v}\right) \tilde{A}_{v}(k)=\tilde{j}(k)^{\mu}
\end{equation}
On physics (https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/640440/gauge-invariant-greens-function-for-electrodynamics) it was said that this equation is non invertible because the differential operator vanishes on $k_{\nu}$. However fixing the gauge, i.e. imposing $\partial_{\nu} A^{\nu}$ makes it invertible. This leads to the retarded and advanced potentials. What is the exact reason why this differential operator is non invertible. I thought it is because its kernel is not zero.

But looking at the equation
\begin{equation}
\square A^{\mu}=j^{\mu}
\end{equation}
the operator $\square$ also has nonzero kernel because it vanishes on harmonic functions. Nonetheless the equation above is invertible.

So when is a differential operator invertible and what has it to do with its kernel?

Comment: An operator with nonzero kernel is never invertible so I'm not sure what you're saying about this box operator. Depending on the choice of domain/decay conditions, maybe there are no nonzero harmonic functions in your context?

Comment: This is exactly my point. In physics they just use a Greens function to write down the solution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retarded_potential). But I don't understand how this is possible without making first the kernel zero. Or is it possible to invert operators with nonzero kernel when adding additional boundary/initial conditions.

Comment: But with this line of argumentation, the other operator should also be invertible, once enough initial data is fixed

Comment: Note that in context of PDEs the term kernel is also used for the integral kernel occuring in a solution theory. These are not completely unrelated, but still do not mean the exact same. So consider the Laplacian $\Delta$ on $L^2(\R^n)$, then the functions $x\mapsto\text{e}^{ik\cdot x}$ are called kernels, and supposing that that they were $L^2$ then they would lie in the kernel (now in the linear map sense) of the eigenvalue operator $\Delta+k^2$. However, they are not $L^2$, but still give rise to a "decomposition" of $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ in terms of the "diagonalizing" Fourier transformation